# Proving If and Only If When X and Y are independent

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be two random variables, defined on some probability space $(\Omega , A , P)$., each only has two district values: $X  \to \{x_1,x_2\}$   , $Y  \to \{y_1,y_2\}$.

Recall that, in this case , $X$ and $Y$ are independent if, of any $i , j (i , j = 1,2)$:

P(X= $x_i$ , Y = $y_i$)  =  P(X = $x_i$)P(Y =$y_i$)

Show that, in this vase, X and Y are independent **if and only if**

E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)

---

My proving Part( if ) Show that

Suppose X and Y are independent. Then for any (x,y) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

p(x,y) = P(X=x , Y=y) = P(X=x) P(Y=y) = p$_x$(x) p$_y$(y)

When p(x,y) = p$_x$(x) p$_y$(y) for all ($x,y)$ $in$ Then for any A $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ and B$\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$  So that

P(X $\in$A , Y $\in$ B) $=\sum_{X \in A} \sum_{y \in B} $ P(X=x , Y=y)

$=\sum_{X \in A} \sum_{y \in B} $  p$_x$(x) p$_y$(y)

$=\sum_{X \in A} $.p$_x$(x) $\sum_{y \in B}$ p$_y$(y)

=P(X $\in$A , Y $\in$ B)

Hence X and Y are independent

---

**** My proving  True or False in part "if"**

**   If can't proving in part  "only if"  . Please help me to proving that.

Comment: It seems like you're showing that $X$ and $Y$ being independent implies that $X$ and $Y$ is independent.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{E}{\mathbf{E}}$

Here is a sketch of a proof.  Normalize the random variables by letting $\tilde{X} = \frac{X - x_1}{x_2-x_1}$ and $\tilde{Y} = \frac{Y - y_1}{y_2 - y_1}$. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are, and use linearity of expectation to show
$$
\E[XY] = \E[X]\E[Y] \iff \E[\tilde{X}\tilde{Y}] = \E[\tilde{X}]\E[\tilde{Y}]
$$

So it is sufficient to prove the claim for two 0-1 random variables.  If $X$ and $Y$ are 0-1 random variables, 
$$
\E[XY] = \E[X]\E[Y] \iff \Pr(X=1, Y=1)=\Pr(X=1)\Pr(X=1)
$$

It is easy to confirm that the latter equality is equivalent to independence of $X$ and $Y$.

**Note:** Since all the implications in this proof are bidirectional, this proves both the "if" and "only if" parts of the question.

Comment: An exercise for the original poster: Show that (by an example!) this conclusion is <b>incorrect</b>   if the two random variables each can take on three or more values.